# How to add files starting with '-' into svn on Windows 10

Tags: svn

i've tried using double quotes, single quotes even a '\' before the hyphen but no joy, eg `svn add "-gl"`

i didn't want to use `svn add . --force` as this would also add files that i didn't want to add.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can try `--targets FILENAME` option for `svn add` and add such names into FILENAME (not tried, I haven't SVN for now)

Comment: Hi, no didn't work, svn add does not have a --targets in version 1.11.1